# Cylinder Hollowness vs Speed Down Incline Plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

We know that the speed of a hollow can is slower down an incline than the speed of a filled can of the same mass and dimensions. If the can is not completely hollow, but not completely filled (so the circumference has a non-zero and < r circumference), one would expect the speed to be in between the two speeds mentioned above.

> Is the relationship here, between the hollowness of a cylinder and the speed, linear? If not, what is it?

Comment: How do you define hollowness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you, say, have a partly hollow can of mass $m$, outer radius $R$ and moment of inertia $I$ around its axis of symmetry, rolling from the height $h$ with angular velocity $\omega$ and speed of the center $v$, then energy conservation gives you:
\begin{equation}
mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2.
\end{equation}
The speed of the center $v=\omega R$, so the eq-n above can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
mgh=\frac{1}{2}\left(mR^2+I\right)\omega^2.
\end{equation}
Now the moment of inertia for a can of a radius $R$ hollow until radius $r<R$ is $I=\pi\rho h/2\left(R^4-r^4\right)$*, where $\rho$ is its density and $h$ is the height. Taking into account that $\rho={m\over V}={m\over\pi(R^2-r^2)h}$ we get
\begin{equation}
mgh=\frac{m}{4}\left(3R^2+r^2\right)\omega^2=\frac{m}{4}\left(3+\frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)v^2.
\end{equation}
And for the velocity you have
\begin{equation}
v=\sqrt{\frac{4gh}{3+\frac{r^2}{R^2}}}.
\end{equation}

For $r=0$ (filled cylinder) you get $v^2={4\over 3}gh$, for $r=R$ (hollow tube) you get $v^2=2gh$.

***** The moment of inertial $I$ for a partly hollow cylinder can be found by integrating

$$
I=\int x^2\mathrm{d}m=\int x^2\rho(x)\mathrm{d}V=\int_0^R x^2 \rho(x) 2\pi x\mathrm{d}xh,
$$

where $\rho(x)=\rho\Theta(x-r)$, where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside function.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Do you mind giving me an online source with all of this? Would you say this is found in any university level physics textbook?

Comment: Do you mean, the energy conservation law, basic dynamics and the definition of the moment of inertia? Well, yes. You can pick any mechanics textbook, i.e., see this one (http://ruina.tam.cornell.edu/Book/RuinaPratap8-21-10.pdf) @ page 668.

Comment: I was looking for this exact derivation from a credible source (such as a textbook). I was not able to find that in the link you provided. Do you know of any credible source that has this derivation?

Comment: No, I mean it's just a simple textbook problem.

Comment: According to your answer, the hollow tube wins (the "race"). Shouldn't the solid cylinder get to the bottom of the incline before the hollow one, and "win the race"?